# ASP.NET MVC Data Annotation DataType.Date for Array

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date, data-annotations

I am using the `DataType(DataType.Date)` data annotation in my models so they are rendered as date-only inputs with an appropriate date picker.

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I have a model which contains an `array` of dates though the data annotation appears to have no effect, is it possible to achieve the same as above?

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime[] Dates { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the html/razor you are using?

Comment: Short answer is no. You could have a property `List<DateModel> Dates` where `DateModel` contains `[DataType(DataType.Date)] public DateTime Date { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment to my question is my accepted answer

> Short answer is no. You could have a property `List<DateModel> Dates`
>   where `DateModel` contains `[DataType(DataType.Date)] public DateTime Date { get; set; }`